# size of button and edittext change with android API 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm developping an android application and it work fine with API 13 to 19, when i test it with API 21 the button size ,edittext and textview change (became bigger).i'm using (match_parent and wrap_content). i find in net that i should add these line `android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"` but i have the same result
this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textAllCaps="false"
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logimage"
    android:layout_width="387px"
    android:layout_height="180px"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:layout_marginTop="40px"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_nearby"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnstart"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:background="#8cd2fc"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80px"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Create account"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@id/logimage"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/btnanonym"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnstart"
    android:layout_marginTop="30px"
    android:text="Connect as anonyme"
    android:background="#00b4e8"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btncnxuser"
    android:background="#00b4e8"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Connect as member"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85px"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnanonym"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:id="@+id/txtinfo"
    android:text="You have already account ?"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnanonym"/>
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/logButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="30px"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:background="#3c5f9d"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Login with Facebook"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btncnxuser"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>
```

xml code using Edittext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#ffffff"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logimage"
    android:layout_width="187sp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_nearby"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/msgerror"
    android:textSize="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/logimage"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="First name"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hinttxt"
    android:background="@color/bluehint"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/txtfirstn"
    android:layout_below="@id/msgerror"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Last name"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:textColorHint="@color/hinttxt"
    android:background="@color/bluehint"
    android:id="@+id/txtlastn"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtfirstn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hinttxt"
    android:background="@color/bluehint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/txtemail"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtlastn"

    />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtemail"
    android:popupElevation="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:hint="Phone"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:textColorHint="@color/hinttxt"
    android:background="@color/bluehint"
    android:id="@+id/txtphone"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Your password"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hinttxt"
    android:background="@color/bluehint"
    android:id="@+id/txtpwd"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtphone"
    />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Re type your password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtrepwd"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hinttxt"
    android:background="@color/bluehint"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtpwd"
    />



<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@color/bluedrawer"
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtrepwd"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/register"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/idH"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@id/idH"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You are using as unit `px` in your `Button` and `TextView`, you should use `dp` instead. May be the problem is there.

Comment: @algui91 thank you it work, if i didn't define any textsize, will the device decide what is the correct size for each screen size?

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using px and sp you have to use dp/dip. It is not become bigger according to phone default styles and resolution or for version > 19.

This practice will be help you for consistent views.

Comment: thank you for your answer. will it cause problem for versoin <19 ?

Comment: No, it is not creating any problem for version < 19.

Comment: sorry i have another question, with editText, i have used dp but the size always big

Comment: If EditText become big, then it will display big for all api versions not for single one API 21. As per the code may not vary for API 21.

Comment: i'm testing with API 15 and API 21 and the size of edittext change. i didn't understand why?

Comment: As you set android:layout_width="match_parent" it will fill as per your parent layout width. You can give specific width then it would be fixed or you can put width into different dimens folder for phone resolution. It will pick correspondence folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are using as unit `px` in your `Button` and `TextView`, you should use `dp` instead. May be the problem is there.

In your `EditText`, you are setting the `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, so it will be as wide as the parent `View`. If what you want is set a especific width, change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the size you want, for example

```
android:layout_height="128dp"
```